# Do you have to use li with ul? HTML Standards

Tags: html

I'm using ul tags in conjunction with css, and, I got the visual effect I wanted from just the ul tags alone.

So I was planning to not use the li tags. But I wasn't sure if that was appropriate in HTML coding standard since I read ul and li tags are always suppose to be used together.

Thanks for the help!

```
<div class="featured_list">
           <ul>
              <a id="f1Link" href="" class="">
                 <div class="image_container"> <img id="f1Pic" src="" alt=""> </div>
                 <div class="info">
                    <h2 id="f1Title"></h2>
                    <h4 id="f1Stock" class=""></h4>
                 </div>
              </a>
              <a id="f2Link" href="" class="">
                 <div class="image_container"> <img id="f2Pic" src="" alt=""> </div>
                 <div class="info">
                    <h2 id="f2Title"></h2>
                    <h4 id="f2Stock" class=""></h4>
                 </div>
              </a>
              <a id="f3Link" href="" class="">
                 <div class="image_container"> <img id="f3Pic" src="" alt=""> </div>
                 <div class="info">
                    <h2 id="f3Title"></h2>
                    <h4 id="f3Stock" class=""></h4>
                 </div>
              </a>
              </ul>
           </div>
```

Comment: If it's not a list then you're using the wrong tags. If it is a list then you're using the wrong tags.

Comment: So it's wrong no matter what? It is a list. But I just wanted to be side-by-side.

Comment: Show us the markup. What are you sticking within `ul` if not `li`?

Comment: @user2898051 If it's a list use `ul` and `li` tags and CSS to style them appropriately.

Comment: There. I've added the code to my question. It's a slideshow.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ should be your source of truth.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly, yes, you need to use `li` with `ul`. The [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) show this error with your code: "Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context." (There were also other errors which I removed for brevity.)

If your content is not a list, you shouldn't be using `ul`. If it is a list, you need to put `li`s in it for it to be semantically correct.

You will probably want to use a `ul` with `li`s inside of it, but with inline styles. Here's an example:

```css
/* Inline list items */
.list-inline {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
.list-inline > li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** Styles borrowed from Bootstrap's [type.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/type.less).

Answer (score 1):

Zero or more li elements is the only permitted content for a ul element according to the spec.

Source:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html

If you have a list, use the li elements and style them. If all you want from the ul is margins and padding and your data is not a list, you would be better off using a styled div.